# How to ensure Liquibase YAML scripts run before SQL scripts in resources in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently developing a Spring Boot application where I'm utilizing Liquibase for managing database schema changes. For defining schema modifications, I've created Liquibase changelog files in YAML format (changelog.yml).

In addition, I have .sql data scripts placed in the src/main/resources/data directory, which are intended to populate the tables created by Liquibase.

My primary concern is ensuring that the Liquibase scripts are executed before the .sql data scripts during the application startup phase. This is essential to prevent potential errors due to absent tables or columns when populating the data. The reason I do not put these sql scripts into another Liquibase script is that it will be very hard to maintain. I just want to change sql scripts necessary according to final look of my tables.

I've attempted to leverage the spring.datasource.data property in my application.properties to specify the .sql data scripts, but I've realized that this approach doesn't guarantee the desired execution order concerning Liquibase scripts.

What is the recommended approach to enforce the desired order of execution, particularly when utilizing Liquibase YAML scripts and Spring Boot's automatic data scripts? Is there a way to explicitly control the sequence of execution, ensuring that Liquibase completes its tasks before the data population scripts are invoked during application startup?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, guidance, or best practices for managing this specific scenario. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You can rewrite your .sql data scripts using liquibase and velocity for example. And order this scripts after your initial liquibase scripts. In this case they will be executed in order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stick to only one method of initializing the database. The Liquibase is a preferred tool.

From Spring documentation:

> If you are using a Higher-level Database Migration Tool, like Flyway or Liquibase, you should use them alone to create and initialize the schema. Using the basic schema.sql and data.sql scripts alongside Flyway or Liquibase is not recommended and support will be removed in a future release.